# Django HttpRequest object not getting the json parameter

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I have been trying to parse the request object to get the json parameters but that json is not passing into the request object

this is my client side, where I am requesting with json.

```
import requests

endpoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api'

get_response = requests.get(endpoint, params={"abc":345}, json={"query":"hi, this is what you are lookig for!"} )

print(get_response.json())
```

and this is my view

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json

def api_home(request, *args, **kwargs): 
    body = request.body
    data = {}
    try:
        data = json.loads(body)
    except:
        pass
    
    print(data)
    return JsonResponse({'message': 'hi there, this is your Django API response'})
```

the output is

```
25/Dec/2022 09:41:49] "GET /api?abc=345 HTTP/1.1" 301 0
{}
```

I am expecting to get this data into my view function

```
{"query":"hi, this is what you are looking for!"}
```

Comment: If you show your codes in text editor, it can be helpful for answer. Not images.

Comment: The code you written is correct, the matter is, when you are using GET method to send http request, you are not able to transfer data with request body, as the length of body part is always 0 in GET method. Try POST instead, and I think your problem will be solved. Happy to help!

Comment: @yxzlwz says it all, also avoid try/except without a specific Error with the except, it will hide all errors

Comment: I really appreciate your time and thoughts.

Comment: I tried by removing the try except block and that says "raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
[25/Dec/2022 14:13:05] "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 500 69541"

Comment: @yxzlwz, I have been following a tutorial and there it works with the get method as well. I may have made a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I figure it out. I was the '/' at the the end of the api (endpoint = "http://localhost:8000/api")

Comment: Fine, I'm sorry for didn't figure out this mistake... After all, add slash or not is really a confusing thing when programming with django or flask